# Ncurses erasing window when I don't want it to

Tags: c++, user-interface, ncurses

I have two windows, one at the top, and one at the bottom (and I will be adding a third window later that will be between those two windows). I draw a horizontal line for the bottom window and then I start drawing the top window, and the bottom window gets erased!

The constructor `display()` is called automatically and than the function `displayMessage()` is called by my code.

Here is the code for `display()`:

```
display::display()
{
  //initialize window
  initscr(); //start curses mode
  cbreak(); //Disable line buffering
  curs_set(0); //Don't show curser
  refresh(); //Now refresh screen

  //setup bottom bar
  bottomBar = newwin(2, 80, 22, 0); //create new window
  whline(bottomBar, '_', 80); //draw line
  wrefresh(bottomBar); //refresh

  //setup top bar
  topBar = newwin(0, 80, 0, 0); //create new window
  wattron(topBar, A_UNDERLINE); //text is to be underlined

}
```

Here is the code for `displayMessage()`:

```
void display::displayMessage(string message)
{
  //do some other necessary stuff
  int length = message.length(); //get length of message
  wmove(topBar, 0, 0); //move curser back to beginning
  //getch();
  wrefresh(topBar); //refresh
  //getch();
  whline(topBar, '_',80); //draw line for bottom
  //getch();
  wmove(topBar, 0, 40 - length/2 - 1); //move cursor to center text
  wprintw(topBar,message.c_str()); //print message
  wrefresh(topBar); //refresh
}
```

In addition here is the code snippets that call those two:

```
//initialize stuff
  pomodoro instance;

  while(true) //loop forever, or until user
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) //loop thru 4 pomodoros
    {
      //work
      instance.Display.displayMessage("**Time to work!**");
      instance.playAlarm();
      //waitForUser();
      //timer(config.workTime);
      //break
      return 0; //doing development right now
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is a problem:

```
  topBar = newwin(0, 80, 0, 0); //create new window
```

because the first parameter is zero.  The [manual page](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_window.3x.html#h3-newwin) explains:

> If either nlines or ncols is zero, they default to
>                 **`LINES - begin_y`** and
>                 **`COLS - begin_x`**.

So the zero-parameter makes your windows overlap (a lot).